# Geometrical Probability

Tags: probability, geometry

$O(2,3)$, $A(2,0)$, $B\left(1,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ are the vertices of $\Delta{OAB}$ on the $\text{x-y}$ plane. Let $\text{R}$ be the region

consisting of all points $P$ inside the triangle, which satisfy:
$$d(P,OA)\geq \min\{d(P,OB), d(P,AB)\} $$

For a random distribution of point P, the probability that it lies in the region $\text{R}$ is of the form: $a-b\sqrt[c]{d}$

$\text{Find:}d^{a}+ c^{b}$$$$$
$d(X,YZ)$ is defined as the perpendicular distance of point (X) on the line $YZ$.

Could somebody be so kind as to please tell me how to answer this? I would indeed be very grateful to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure about the vertices coordinates? I have a method that is easy but it does not fall in the format you gave, probably because of the coordinates...

Comment: Actually, my friend gave me this question and he was coninved it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I don't have the answer to the right format, but it is I think the easiest solution.

The probability of the point $P$ being in the region is $1$ minus the probability that the point $P$ is in the region where it is closest to the side $OA$ than to any other side.

This probability is the ratio $\dfrac{Area(OAI)}{Area(OAB)}$, with $I$ being the incenter of the triangle $OAB$.

The distance between $I$ and $OA$ is the radius $r$ of the incircle.

But $r=\dfrac{Area(OAB)}{\frac{p}{2}}=\dfrac{2Area(OAB)}{p}$, with $p$ being the perimeter of $OAB$.

And $Area(OAI)=\frac 12 r \times OA=\frac32 r=\dfrac{3\times Area(OAB)}{p}$

The probability is then $P=1-\frac{3}{p}$

You have then to compute the perimeter $p=OA+AB+OB$

But this does not give any "simple" result, in the form you mention.